# Why use 'I are' 'You is'?

Tags: american-english, slang

I've seen many American and English people writing their sentences like this:

> I are...
>   You is...

---

While the way I've learned it, and seen most widely used is like this:

> I am
>   You are

---

Is this some kind of a slang, or have I missed an English lesson?

Comment: +1 for "or have I missed an English lesson?" -- No, you sure haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am* and *you are* are the Standard English forms. In other dialects, the same form is used for all persons and numbers, so it is unlikely that a speaker of a nonstandard dialect would use both *I are* and *you is*. It would normally be *are* throughout or *is* throughout. As the sociolinguist Peter Trudgill says [here](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/SEtrudgill.htm):

> Standard English has irregular forms of the verb *to be* both in the
>   present tense (*am, is, are*) and in the past (*was, were*). Many
>   nonstandard dialects have the same form for all persons, such as *I be,
>   you be, he be, we be, they be*, and *I were, you were, he were, we were,
>   they were.*

Comment: So it's correct if you say *He be* for example?

Comment: It's grammatical in a dialect which uses *be* for all persons and numbers. It is not grammatical in Standard English, which is the dialect non-native speakers learn. In Standard English  the third person singular present tense of _be_ is _He is_, not _He be_, and it is that which you should use.

Comment: As I could understand from this: It is not Standard English, so you won't need to use it in your speech, as long as you understand what someone means by it.

Comment: Correct. You will hear all sorts of things in English which, as a foreign learner, you will not have been taught, and for most purposes you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: +1 I suppose it's blindingly obvious when I think about it, but until now I hadn't been consciously aware that all those nonstandard dialectal verb forms invariably result from *reduction* of the full conjugations. Thus they can reasonably be seen as "forward-looking" simplifications, rather than ignorant "mixing up" of the standard forms.